# Visual Studio - black line at the bottom in portrait mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, user-interface, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem with a black line appearing at the bottom of Visual Studio. This happens only if I move the window to my monitor which is in portrait mode and only for VS. It doesn't appear for any other program. In VS2010 it's not such a big problem:

[image: Visual Studio 2010 with black line]
However in VS2013 it partially covers the status bar which is really annoying:

[image: Visual Studio 2013 with black line]
Has anyone encountered this kind of behavior?
Thanks for any tips on how to fix this.

Comment: Have you managed to fix this?